# Very weird database insertion/selecting phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, phpmyadmin

I am using CodeIgniter with my own PDO statements (hard coded). I am getting an error in phpmyadmin when I try to click on the id that is a foreign key to another table. *if using a foreign key in Phpmyadmin the foreign key will appear as a hyperlink to that table*

This is an example : [image: error]

However when I go to command line I get this :

```
mysql> select * from session WHERE anum = 'A00163047';
+------------+-----------+------+---------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+
| session_id | anum      | why  | aidyear | signintime          | studentcomments | status |
+------------+-----------+------+---------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+
|        184 | A00163047 |    4 | 14-15   | 2013-02-17 23:21:47 |                 |      0 |
+------------+-----------+------+---------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also just to note, they are different Id's but still none the less the error is persistent.

It seems as if adding the anum = 'whatever id' seems to return a query. Should I be worried about when it comes to retrieving the data to put in a table?

I tried to replicate this with both XSS on, and off (globally) i tried every different feasible combination of the form_validation and still I get the same error. Why is this so? This is making me worry that my data is being corrupted some where.

Edit 1 :

based on the responses people think that an actual value is _27A0000000_27

**THIS IS NOT** the case. When I click on the phpmyadmin hyperlink _27(whatever)_27 is being added giving me an error. I know how to select

eg : `select * from whatever WHERE anum = 'Whatever';`

EDIT 2 :

[image: Test]

When you hit the hyperlink in phpmyadmin there will be a select statement like so generated automatically :

[image: Testing11]

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using that generates that statement?

Comment: In original query, you are selecting from session table but in error, the table used is different....I think, u've error in associated query...

Comment: The statement in phpmyadmin? or my actual PDO?

Comment: @LolCoder I only added two queries for examples. The error is being caused by phpmyadmin adding _27(to what ever anum)_27 but in command line the data and query works just fine.

Comment: look at original post please

Answer (score 2):

Must be an encoding problem. 0x27 is the ASCII hex value of the single quote character (`'`)

Or is your PDO coded in a manner that it eacapes the single quotes?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the value in Quotes, because varchar field's value should be always enclosed in quotes.

So the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM `citest`.`student`

WHERE `anum` = '_27A00000000_27'

Limit 0,30
```

Thanks.

Comment: I know how to select queries, Look at the example I gave in the OP. The problem is that the value is not _27A0000000_27 it is A00000000 so for some reason _27(whatever)_27 is being added to my anum =

Comment: look at original post please